# Can I use export command in precommit hook to get a single file with head revision?

Tags: svn

When I ran the export command in precommit hook. It is not getting a file. I have also tried to to run svn.exe in pre-commit hook, it is not working. I want to know that in pre-commit have some restriction to run svn.exe. I have getting a single file using export command with head rev in any batch file except precommit hook.

thanks,

Comment: Please don't say "it's not working". Describe what you're doing (having the actual code is very helpful), what output you receive, and what you *expected/wanted* to happen.

Comment: To answer your question, the pre-commit hook doesn't have any restrictions about running `svn.exe` itself, but depending on what exactly you're doing and how, it may not be possible due to the data not being available at that point in time.

Comment: @alroc your comment is the answer to the question, why dont you put it as an answer?

Comment: @FaustoCarvalhoMarquesSilva the question isn't fully answerable in its current form - his pre-commit isn't working as desired, and not enough information has been provided to explain why. I *can* make it an answer, but I don't think it will actually answer the question at hand.

Comment: hooks are executed in clean environment (none environment variables as part of this state), thus - you **must always** use full path to executables. But anyway, using svn in pre-commit hook for transaction is The Wrong Way (tm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @alroc had perfectly valid and correct answer ("Show, **what** not working and **how**"), I have to add

- svnlook is better suited for using in hooks
- `svnlook cat` output any file, affected by transaction (which pre-commit hook inspects in the process of running)